# How to really make proguard keep everything, just like there's no proguard?

Tags: android-studio, proguard

I'm using Android Studio, and have problems when exporting signed APK. My app runs well in debug mode, but having tons of problems with signed APK.

I think the problem is proguard did something to my app, but there are too many problems and I am not able to find and fix them. Is there a way to tell proguard just don't do anything, or is there a way to not using Proguard in Android Studio?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464035/how-to-tell-proguard-to-keep-everything) does not work.