# How do you use proguard just to replace class names and variables?

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8, android-obfuscation

I had a horrible time with proguard and ultimately decided not to use it to remove code. Instead I intent to use it just to replace the variable and classes name just so that my code is not all available with a simple JDAX decompile. Anyone knows how to use proguard (or R8) to just simply "obfuscate" the code (i.e. minify the variable/class names) without removing code? Also is there anything better than proguard (R8) for obfuscating purposes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell ProGuard to keep everything in a particular package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464035/how-to-tell-proguard-to-keep-everything-in-a-particular-package) You can disable code shrinking and other optimizations, but leave the obfuscation step. Although I encourage you to look further into it, there's really no point in shipping an app full of useless code, two or three times the size it could have been without it. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: It's just a nightmare... I am using JNI and C++ a lot so I don't really want to remove anything, just obguscate the code