# How to tell proguard to not remove a lamda function parameter?

Tags: android, proguard

I have a kotlin class GitManager.

One of its method its method is

```
suspend fun cloneRepo(
    progressCallback: (Int) -> Unit
)
```

This method will then call an external function:

```
private external fun cloneRepoLib(
    progressCallback: (Int) -> Unit
)
```

I can call this lamda function in C++ when i run my app in Debug but in release, proguard seems to remove it.

I tried to define a global variable

```
@Keep
private var processCallback: (Int) -> Unit = { }
```

But this doesn't solve anything.

So the question is, how can i tell proguard to not remove this lamda function parameter?

Fyi, the full class path is com.example.gitnote.manager.GitManager.

**Edit based on the comment of Dan Getz**

Fist of all, the type of my call back is actually ((Int) -> Unit)? to be able to use CallbackHandler for push and pull. I didn't include it in the question to simplify. I also didn't mention some others parameters.

This is my C++ class that handle the callback:

```cpp
#include "CallbackHandler.h"


bool isInit = false;

CallbackHandler::CallbackHandler(JNIEnv *env, jobject progressCallback) {
    if (progressCallback == nullptr) {
        return;
    }

    this->env = env;
    this->progressCallbackObj = progressCallback;
    jclass callbackClass = env->GetObjectClass(progressCallbackObj);
    this->callbackMethodId = env->GetMethodID(callbackClass, "invoke", "(I)V");
    isInit = true;
}


void CallbackHandler::progressCallback(int percent) {
    if (isInit) {
        env->CallVoidMethod(progressCallbackObj, callbackMethodId, percent);
    }
}
```

The error i'm having is:

```
java_vm_ext.cc:594] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: mid == null
java_vm_ext.cc:594]     in call to CallVoidMethodV
java_vm_ext.cc:594]     from int com.example.gitnote.manager.GitManagerKt.cloneRepoLib(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1)
...
runtime.cc:675]   at com.example.gitnote.manager.GitManagerKt.cloneRepoLib(Native method)
runtime.cc:675]   at com.example.gitnote.manager.GitManagerKt.a(unavailable:0)
```

Comment: Could you give more details about what exactly is removed, or what errors you're seeing? You say the parameter, which makes it sound like you're saying `cloneRepo` is still there but is now a method with no parameters. But how is `cloneRepoLib` called if the parameter is not there? Is the call to `cloneRepoLib` also removed? Are you sure `cloneRepo` is still there?

Comment: @DanGetz I edited the question with more info. I think it's only the callback that is removed

Comment: Is `isInit` a field of the `CallbackHandler` object, or a global value? The way it's set and read, it seems like it should be a field.

Comment: I'm not an expert of C++, but i guess it is a field of the `CallbackHandler` class. It is not declared in the .h if this what you meant. I added some logs and i'm sure the error is when `env->CallVoidMethod` is called.

Comment: It's been a while since I did much C++, but from what I remember, fields are defined inside the class definition, like in Java and Kotlin. If it's not a field but a global instead, that appears to be a bug to me: if you create two or more `CallbackHandlers`, they share the same value for `isInit` but not the fields. So you could have `isInit` be `true` because handler B has a `progressCallbackObj`, but handler A might not be initialized. This might not be causing your specific error, though... could you check in the constructor if `callbackMethodId` is null?

Comment: I suggest you look at the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/q/7464035/3004881 ... they involve turning off different parts of ProGuard so as to keep callbacks around, similar to your case. Maybe if you tell it to not remove any methods named `invoke` inside your package? I think `@Keep` won't help you here because it would need to be on `fun invoke`, but that's not explicitly written in your code.