# Android Proguard: Keep Classes but obfuscate class names

Tags: android, android-proguard

I am unable to both keep some classes with proguard but still obfuscate their names. I also want to keep an Interface and their method names and also keep all implementations of this interface with the correct name.

What I have tried:

```
-keep public class a.b.c.** # doesn't obfuscate class names
-keepclassmembers class a.b.c.** # classes aren't kept anymore
-keep public interface a.b.c.D {*;}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633411/android-proguard-only-obfuscation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145540/how-to-enabling-proguard-obfuscation-in-android-studio/35145658#35145658